# Get all the unique entries from 2 tables

Tags: ios, sql, sqlite

I have 2 tables, i want to get all the entries from 2 tables which are not duplicates e.g.
as shown below

```
Table1
MID,  ITEM, PRICE, QUANTITY
1000  ab    10     5
2000  bc    20     6

Table2
MID,  ITEM, PRICE, QUANTITY
3000  cd    30     4
1000  ed    10     7
```

Result should be

```
MID,  ITEM, PRICE, QUANTITY
3000  cd    30     4
1000  ed    10     7
2000  bc    20     6
```

Kindly let me know by using which SQLite query this can be achieved?

Comment: And why your out put doesn't contain `1000 ab 10 5` if you want distinct record of `MID` then what is your criteria that your result should be `1000 ed 10 7` ?

Comment: The records from Table2 should be selected if same entries are present in Table 1 and Table 2

Comment: How do you define "**same entries**"?

Comment: I want to compare with MID columns from 2 tables and get the unique entries from 2 tables.

Comment: Be specific and to the point in your question  itself so that community can provide more accurate solution initially and that will help in understandings :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a simple way of expressing your logic:

```
select *
from table2
union all
select *
from table1
where table1.mid not in (select mid from table2)
```

Take everything from `table2`.  Then take the extra rows from `table1`, based on `mid`.

Answer (score 1):

Per your comment, you could filter out rows from `Table1` that are also in `Table2`:

```
select  *
from    Table1 t1
where   not exists
        (
        select  *
        from    Table2 t2
        where   t1.mid = t2.mid
                and t1.item = t2.item
        )
union all
select  *
from    Table2
```

I'm assuming that `(mid, item)` is unique in each individual table.

Comment: I want to union the all records and get all the unique records by comparing MID column.

Comment: The MID column is only unique and not both mid & item. Could you please modify if needed. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

According to your requirement that  **to compare with MID** and if duplicate entry found get the result from Table 2

This query will help u :

```
select  * from  Table1 
where MID  not in ( select distinct MID from Table2 )
union 
select  mid,item,price,quantity from    Table2;
```

have a look on this **[Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/df779/12)**

Thanks.